# JCrop resizing the image not cropping - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jcrop

I am trying to use JCrop to crop an image. However the results are frustratingly wrong and I am not sure why. I have an image uploader that when someone selects in image a javascript changes the source of an image already on the page to match the newly upload image. I then have this code:

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#image-editor-preview img")
            .attr("src", "/Profiles/AvatarWorker/" + _id + "?random=" + Math.random())
                        .Jcrop({
                            aspectRatio: 1,
                            setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50],
                            minSize: [160, 160],
                            maxSize: [160, 160],
                            onChange: setCoords,
                            onSelect: setCoords
                        });
    }
});

var x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0;
function setCoords(c) {
    x = c.x;
    y = c.y;
    w = c.w;
    h = c.h;
};
```

However this is what happens:

[image]

I have tried tried quite a bit to fix this but the end results are ALWAYS the same. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the source for your function `setCoords`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Turns out that JCrop inside a twitter bootstrap modal has an issue with the width of the JCrop box. The twitter bootstrap modal is overriding the CSS inside the JCrop css. Had to modify the CSS in JCrop to not have this happen.

Comment: @Bungdaddy Oof, this was long ago. Another person commented on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11207459/692197 . What he did sounds about right with what I did. The cropping tool was inheriting the css from the modal. I believe had to remove the height and width to fix the issue in the jcrop css file.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, but I found, why it happens so.

In my css file I had this code:

```
img {
    width:  100%;
    height: auto;
    border: none;
}
```

When I removed width and height from this definition, plugin started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Jcrop docs, it does not actually do the cropping.  It only creates a image cropping UI.  It then depends on the server doing the actual cropping; see http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Implementation_Theory.html .  So it looks like the plugin is doing exactly what it is designed to do.  It's now leaving the rest for you to do yourself on the server, as they show.

Comment: Saving the image isn't the problem. The cropping tool is the problem. I have it able to save the image with the coordinates. The fact that it isn't working with the given image is what I am not understanding. I am not sure why its morphing the given image as opposed to showing a cropped area of the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you intend your code to do then; at a quick glance, it looks like, when a selection or change event occurs, you immediately reset it with setCoords.  Esp onChange - "Called when the selection is moving"; you're never letting the user actually set coords, if I follow correctly, since you're immediately resetting back to x = 0, y = 0, w = 0, h = 0.  Again, just a guess, but I think it's then seeing an invalid selection, and just using your default selection - setSelect: [100, 100, 50, 50].  The callback to showCoords() in the examples seems to be an accessor func, not a setter.

Comment: Since you're then setting an image size of 160x160, on an image which is 100x50, it looks like it's stretching that 100x50 image to 160x80, inside a 160x160 box.

Comment: Side note, I might be able to use this plugin in something I'm currently working on.  I'd be grateful to see the "saving the cropped section" code you have, if it works client-side without the server run.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Turns out that JCrop inside a twitter bootstrap modal has an issue with the width of the JCrop box. The twitter bootstrap modal is overriding the CSS inside the JCrop css. Had to modify the CSS in JCrop to not have this happen. As far as client side work I am not sure I can post that code as it's work related. I'll see what I can do. It is C# code in MVC3.