# Twitter bootstrap cropper image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, jcrop

I currently develop a website and clients need a section to upload profile image then modify image profile exactly same the way Twitter does.

I wonder whether jcrop can handle it or there are any bootstrap plugins to achieve that functionality ?

As I observed that Twitter doesn't really crop the image, instead of it takes a screenshot for whatever inside the div overlay and process the content to an image.

Is my guess correct or there are any techniques to achieve this task ?

[image]

Comment: Jcrop will handle it just fine... or any other js/jquery plugin that finds coordinates of an image for you will do the trick. All you are doing with the plugin is getting the coordinates of the cropped area and sending them to the server so that the server can perform the image manipulation.

Comment: what is your question and what has this to do with Twitter's Bootstrap. Yes Jcrop can do this, see also: or try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10538970/jcrop-resizing-the-image-not-cropping-javascript https://pypi.python.org/pypi/clean-image-crop-uploader/0.2.1 or http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery/image_upload_crop.php etc.

Comment: If you're still looking, try this: http://danielhellier.com/imagecrop/